# Make requireJS intellisense in Visual Studio 2013-2015

Tags: javascript, requirejs, visual-studio-2015, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

This seems a simple problem, but I can't find any information online about it, neither here in Stack Overflow.

I am having problems making Intellisense work under Visual Studio 2013/2015 with RequireJS (client-side).

In theory you only need to add a reference in the _references.js file, like this:

```
/// <reference path="libs/require.js" data-main="main.js" start-page="../default.htm" />
```

but I get this message all the time through the Output window regarding the "JavaScript Language Service":

[Error regarding RequireJS path in VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjuTm.png)

It seems as if the feature was trying to load my "main.js" file from the VS JavaScript references folder instead of my real folder which gets a lot of "../" added and can not be resolved. In fact the suggested path that can't be loaded it's OK except for all the "../".

I've tried diverse combinations of relative paths to write the attributes, but no luck.

This is very annoying and I can't find any reliable info on the Web regarding this specific problem. The only reference I've found is this one:

http://blog.nansen.com/2015/09/getting-visual-studio-intellisense-to.html

and they suggest to add a baseUrl config code to the _references.js file, which hasn't worked for me at all.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

And by the way: any reference on how to make this work under VS Code also?

Comment: I see no comments on this. I'm having the same issue, did you figure it out?

Comment: Sorry, I missed your notification. No, I didn't figure out how to do it. If I get it to work I'll put it here.

Answer (score -2):

Found out that it related to the solution/project that is on another drive letter.

VS studio is installed on drive `C:` and the solution/project is on drive `D:`.

Have not found a solution to this problem, but can be corrected by moving to drive `C:`.